python backtracking debug
This is a minimal reproducible code, so please do not concern about the meaningfulness of the code.
I want to input a list with one element, and return once it grows to length of 5. So I use a recursion to do it. But somehow the append and pop cause res variable to update unintentionally. Could you help me find why? Many thanks!
def test(x):
    res = []
    
    def helper(x):
        if len(x) == 5:
            res.append(x)
            print(f"{x=},{res=}")
            return
        print(f"{x=},{res=}")
        x.append(x[-1] + 1)
        helper(x)
        x.pop()
        print(f"{x=},{res=}")
    helper(x)
    return res

test([0])

I use inline print to debug. As you can see from the result, the recursion base case can update the res. But then it is gone! I thought the x will be popped out but not the res
x=[0],res=[]
x=[0, 1],res=[]
x=[0, 1, 2],res=[]
x=[0, 1, 2, 3],res=[]
x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],res=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
x=[0, 1, 2, 3],res=[[0, 1, 2, 3]]
x=[0, 1, 2],res=[[0, 1, 2]]
x=[0, 1],res=[[0, 1]]
x=[0],res=[[0]]


"Unintentionally": What is not intended? Did you expect the list not to change after having reached size 5? On the way out of recursion you still execute as many res.pop() as you did res.append(). Add a print right after the pop() and you'll see.

Sorry I didn’t write clearly. I just edited. Yes, I thought the x list will be popped out, but why the res?

Isnt it expected that if you append and then pop again?

Thank you @trincot! So my question is:
After dfs to x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], the base case condition is satisfied, so res gets updated. Then when x pops, why res still gets updated? Because the base condition is no longer satisfied.

You append x to res, then you proceed to empty x. So in the end res contains emptied x. Not sure what's confusing you here? Maybe you wanted res.append(x.copy()) so that later emptying x doesn't affect the content of res?
